# Usar diseño generado en Qt Designer y convertido a módulo Python (.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

Tengo este módulo convertido de **untitled.ui** a **untitled.py** entiendo que no lo puedo modificar manualmente.

Necesito conectar los botones para que el **`pushbutton_2`** limpie el **`lineedit`** y **l`ineedit_2`** y el **`pushButton_3`** cierre la ventana.

---

Adjunto código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 210, 295, 30))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 100, 141, 55))
        self.widget1.setObjectName("widget1")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget1)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ello lo que se hace es importar la clase `UI_MainWindow` en tu módulo principal. Luego puedes usar simplemente herencia múltiple, heredando de `QtWidgets.QMainWindow`(o de la clase base correspondiente) y de tu clase `UI_MainWindow`. Luego simplemente en el inicializador de tu clase llamas al método `setupUI` heredado de `UI_MainWindow`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore,  QtWidgets
from untitled import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,  Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,  self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self._clear)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.close)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def _clear(self):
        self.lineEdit.clear()
        self.lineEdit_2.clear()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

En este caso el .py generado a partir del .ui se llamaría `untitled.py` y debe estar en el mismo directorio que tu `main.py`.

Comment: muchas gracias si es posible me podrias explicar a que hace referencia @QtCore.pyqtSlot() ?

Comment: @BrunoOviedo es un decorador que permite especificar de forma explícita un método Python  como un slot de Qt y proporciona una firma C++ para él.  Esto permite entre otras cosas el mapeo explícito de los tipos, consiguiendo mejoras en rendimiento y uso de memoria. Puedes mirarte http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator para más información. Es una costumbre mía en gran parte arrastrada de PySide, no es imprescindible en la mayoría de los casos, en tu caso puedes eliminarlo si lo deseas, no vas tampoco a notar diferencia alguna.

Comment: Lo ultimo:

Tengo 2 QlLineEdit (valor1, valor2) quiero que al poner los números en valor 1 se realice una multiplicación * 3.6 y se muestre de inmediato en valor2.
En este momento la tengo con un Qpushbutton y funciona bien, pero quiero eliminar ese Qpushbutton.

Comment: Si quieres que se realice el cálculo de manera automática considera agregar un validador al QLineEdit para que el usuario no pueda ingresar otra cosa que no sean valores numéricos: `validator = QtGui.QDoubleValidator()`,
`self.lineedit.setValidator(validator)`. Después simplemente conecta el slot  que ya tienes asociado al botón a la señal `editingFinished()` o `textChanged()`/`textEdited()` del `QLineEdit` dependiendo del comportamiento que quieras. La primera realizará el cálculo al pulsar enter o perder el foco, las otras dos de forma inmediata en cuando el texto sea modificado.

Answer (score 0):

desde el editor de formularios puedes enlazar la señal [`clicked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) de `QPushButton` con el slot [`clear`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#clear) del `QLineEdit`.

Más información: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-connection-mode.html

Disculpa que la respuesta sea tan corta pero no tiene sentido salpicarla de las imágenes del enlace.

Comment: si lo realice desde el formulario, pero quiero hacerlo de forma manual.... en otro modulo

Comment: Pues entonces tienes que hacer la conexión a mano... desconozco la sintaxis en python... en C++ sería `connect(pushbutton_2,SIGNAL(clicked()),lineedit_2,SLOT(clear()));`